# А где содержимое правки?

Tags: поддержка, правки

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/713682/revisions

Что поменялось в третьей ревизии?
Если ничего, то где [соответствующее сообщение](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3299/178988)?

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 1):

Похоже это какой-то баг, связанный с [новым функционалом](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/339911) утверждения отклонённых или отклонения утверждённых правок автором сообщения.

Вторая редакция как раз производит уменьшение сообщения на 39 символов.

В общем, я оформил баг репорт на MSE по этой теме: [Empty revision possibly after approving suggested edit by post owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300454/339911)

<sub>P.S. Можем поэкспериментировать на текущем вопросе, если есть желание :)</sub>